# Accessing main.js file from 1 angular app exporting angular element into a container angular app

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, angular-elements

`I have 2 angular applications running on localhost:4200 and localhost:4201.

In localhost:4200, I have converted the complete AppComponent into an angular element .

I have built the project, concatenated all the .js files into a main.js file.

If I try to access this main.js file in the index.html of the app running on localhost:4201 using

```
<script src="http://localhost:4200/main.js"></script>,
```

then the main.js does get downloaded but the angular element does not show in the component.

If copy the main.js from localhost:4200 to the assets of localhost:4021 and reference the path of the file "src/assets/main.js" in scripts of angular.json, then it works perferctly.

But for runtime integration, I need to access the main.js via script tag. How do I make it work ?

Below didn't work in localhost:4201

```
  <script src="http://localhost:4200/main.js"></script>
```

Below worked in localhost:4201

```
 "scripts": ["src/assets/main.js"]
```

But for runtime integration, the `<script>` solution needs to work.

Comment: why would you need something like this? You are probably better off using vanilla js. Angular builds the components in the app, exporting the main.js through script just passes the plain js to the other build. If you need components that work in multiple projects you should build a library.

Comment: I am using the angular framework and building microfrontends. Using angular elements or web components to construct the microfrontends. To integrate them into a container app, looking for a solution that works at runtime.

Comment: Angular libraries is also a build time integration solution.